# Is server-side code in 'Single file aspx' compiled into a single dll in Web Application type of project?

Tags: asp.net, compilation

If I have pages having server-side code in code-behind, then I know that the code-behind for all such pages will get compiled into a single intermediate language dll, when using a Web Application type of project.
But, if I have some single file aspx pages (i.e. pages with inline server-side code) in the same Web Application project, I am thinking that the server-side code for these inline aspx's will not be part of the single dll that is generated for a Web application project. Is this true?
My impression is that single-file aspx pages are always compiled on-the-fly and never pre-compiled.

Comment: Saw this on MSDN : These files are split into markup and source code, which includes code-behind files. Source code is compiled into assemblies, with names that are derived from a hashing algorithm, and the assemblies are placed in the Bin directory. Any inline code, that is, code enclosed in <script runat="server"> elements, is included with markup and not compiled. New files with the same name as the source files are created to contain the markup and placed in the corresponding output directories.

Comment: The above comment applies to Web Site model, and not to a Web Application model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It will be compiled on fly if it is inline in the `ASPX` file itself. But this will happen only once. After that it will be cached until the `ASPX` file is changed. So from the second request onwards both will be treated same.

You can [read](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/code-behind-vs-inline-code.html) this

It is advisable to use single file when you expect the code to be changed frequently and you do not need to recompile the entire code.

Also here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link for more details.

**Note**: You can have a single DLL with all code or you can have different DLLs for each page.

Comment: So single file aspx will have some performance hit when first requested, no matter how small this hit?

Comment: Yes. It will be the time to compile it for the first time.